# how to detect element drag in d3.js force directed graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a force directed graph in d3.js (Brilliant: big kudos to MB and all involved!). I'd like to somehow be able to detect, and return the index of any node that's currently being dragged.

I know that I can redefine d3.behavior.drag() to attach a callback to the drag event, but I want all the behavior of the native force.drag and it seems clumsy to reduplicate it all just to add this one little bit. In my inexperience, perhaps I'm overlooking some straightforward way to do this?

---

hmm, yes, I should be more explicit. This is what I tried: I've used the example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292) as my model, modifying it to suit my purposes, and learning d3.js as I go. I defined the nodes thus:

```
var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .on("click", clicked)
    .on("dblclick", dblclick)
    .on("contextmenu", cmdclick)
    .on("drag", draghandler)
    .call(force.drag);

function draghandler(d){
    console.log(d);
    console.log(this);
}
```

My event handlers for `click`, `dblclick`, and `contextmenu`, work exactly as I expect; however, when I try to add an event handler for `drag`, it never executes. I imagined that it was failing because I was using it wrong, or in the wrong place, or that because the behavior is governed by `force.drag`, I would have to redefine that to add the additional behavior I wanted.

Comment: The way to do this is to do it in the `drag` event handler. There's no redefinition involved in this.

Comment: Many thanks @LarsKotthoff, that was my first thought, but clearly I'm doing it wrong. Have added further exposition.

Comment: I think in this case the event is `force.drag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `drag` event is not fired by `circle`, it's fired by the the drag behavior ([source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js#L286-L291)), calling `force.drag` will return that behavior and you can set a listener there:

```
force.drag()
  .on("dragstart", function () {
    console.log(arguments);
  })
```

[Demo](http://bl.ocks.org/maurizzzio/dcf8e997e39ddcf7f521), see the console's output

Update:

I forked the example link you posted which doesn't use `d3.json` and it's working fine: [demo](http://bl.ocks.org/maurizzzio/65558c49cbe81c81a395)

Comment: Many thanks Mauricio, that's illuminating, and looks very promising; however, you're calling `force.drag()` in the context of the `d3.json()` callback. In MBs example, which is my model, `d3.json()` isn't used. If I try it in my context, the global level of the script, I get: "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined"`. Where can I call `force.drag` to set that listener?

Comment: you should set it after the variable `force` is created, I've updated my answer

Comment: Your answer is both illuminating and correct; however, I've been unable to duplicate your success. In order to illustrate my continuing problem, I copied my code to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjon/tuqc31zt/), only to discover that your solution works there perfectly. Locally, however, I continue to get the following errors:
`TypeError: this[type] is undefined d3.v2.js:3005`
`TypeError: path is undefined force-directed-edges.html:274`
To illustrate further I've put up the page [here](http://neolography.com/force-directed-edges.html), where, in my browser, it fails. Any ideas?

Comment: the question you now ask is out of the scope of the original one, however I see from the code that d3's version is not the latest, there's a check present on d3's [source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js#L286-L291) which is not in the source code of the local d3 version you have, this line is missing: `if (!arguments.length) return drag;`

Comment: Yes! Locally, I was loading d3.js from this url `http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?1.29.1` which I think I was inheriting from some older example. Using the latest version of d3.min.js from the github repo fixed it. Above, beyond, and out-of-scope. Many thanks.